# How to change of basis from 3 points in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra

Let R and S be two 2D coordinate systems.
I know the coordinate of 3 non-aligned points A,B,C in both systems.

How can I find the coordinate of O,P (or any other point from S) in R?

[image: desc]

Sorry for the poor wording, I'm not familiar with mathematical stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't give some definite relation between the points I'm afraid the question cannot be solved...

Comment: What kind of relation is required? A,B,C are arbitrary points. I just know theirs coordinates. From the above picture: B could be (2.5, 3.3) in base S and (2.2, 2.3) in base R. Is A,B and C enough to compute point O? (0,0) in S and (Xr,Xy) in R